# NetworkX graph with some specifications based on two dataframes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have two dataframes. The first shows the name of people of a program, called `df_student`.

| Student-ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 20202456 | Luke De Paul |
| 20202713 | Emil Smith |
| 20202456 | Alexander Müller |
| 20202713 | Paul Bernard |
| 20202456 | Zoe Michailidis |
| 20202713 | Joanna Grimaldi |
| 20202456 | Kepler Santos |
| 20202713 | Dominic Borg |
| 20202456 | Jessica Murphy |
| 20202713 | Danielle Dominguez |

And the other shows a dataframe where people reach the best grades with at least one person from the `df_student` in a course and is called `df_course`.

| Course-ID | Name | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UNI44 | Luke De Paul, Benjamin Harper | 17 |
| UNI45 | Dominic Borg | 20 |
| UNI61 | Luke De Paul, Jonathan MacAllister | 20 |
| UNI62 | Alexander Müller, Kepler Santos | 17 |
| UNI63 | Joanna Grimaldi | 19 |
| UNI65 | Emil Smith, Filippo Visconti | 18 |
| UNI71 | Moshe Azerad, Emil Smith | 18 |
| UNI72 | Luke De Paul, Jessica Murphy | 18 |
| UNI73 | Luke De Paul, Filippo Visconti | 17 |
| UNI74 | Matthias Noem, Kepler Santos | 19 |
| UNI75 | Luke De Paul, Kepler Santos | 16 |
| UNI76 | Kepler Santos | 17 |
| UNI77 | Kepler Santos, Benjamin Harper | 17 |
| UNI78 | Dominic Borg, Kepler Santos | 18 |
| UNI80 | Luke De Paul, Gabriel Martin | 18 |
| UNI81 | Dominic Borg, Alexander Müller | 19 |
| UNI82 | Luke De Paul, Giancarlo Di Lorenzo | 20 |
| UNI83 | Emil Smith,Joanna Grimaldi | 20 |

I would like to create a `NetworkX` graph where there is a vertex for each student from `df_student` and also from each student from `df_course`. There should also be an unweighted each between two vertices only if two student received the best grade in the same course.

Now what I tried is this

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(student, course)
```

But when I doing is it say that argument is not right. And so I don't know how to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df_students = pd.read_clipboard()
df_course = pd.read_clipboard()



df_s_t = df_course['Name'].str.split(',', expand=True)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_net, 0, 1)

df_net = df_s_t[df_s_t.notna().all(1)]

G.add_nodes_from(pd.concat([df_students['Name'], 
                            df_s_t.loc[~df_s_t.notna().all(1),0]]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,15))
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

Output:

[image]